# Can't see Android Studio install wizard on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: android, ubuntu

I just installed the new version of Ubuntu (17.10) but now if I try to install Android Studio by running "studio.sh" it doesn't show the install wizard. It's there but I can't see it. Does anyone know how to get it to display? This is a fresh install of both.

Update: I've found a workaround. If I alt + ~ then I can see the preview image and I can actually use this to navigate through the wizard and get it to work. But this isn't really ideal. The wizard is apparently on the screen and I can interact with it via the keyboard, I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the studio.sh file using the command below.
(I assume you have extracted the archive in your home directory)

$cd android-studio/bin

~/android-studio/bin$./studio.sh

It will open a wizard for basic setup like downloading sdk etc.

Comment: I realise that but the wizard is not visible. It's technically there since I can interact with it but I can't see it. Have you tried it on Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: I use in ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Have you tried after a reboot? It may fix the problem.

Comment: 16.04 works fine. The question relates specifically to 17.10.